# vba - automatically move to next cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have to enter lots of 5-digits set numbers (e.g. 12345, 23456)into column A.

Is there an way to automatically move to next row on column A as soon as I enter 5-digits number in my activate cell?

Comment: Do you mean without touching the **ENTER** key ??

Comment: You can, but you [should not](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/11683).

Comment: @Gary'sStudent, Yes, that's what i mean.

Comment: While there are some great solutions here, honestly you would gain more by becoming more proficient at data entry in the usual way. Unless you plan on only typing a constant string of 5 digit characters for the next few months, in which case... consider a new career path...

Answer (score 3):

First format column **A** to *Text*

Then enter the following *Event Macro* in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim A As Range, L2 As Long, Leftover As Long
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    Set A = Range("A:A")
    If Intersect(Target, A) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    v = Target.Text
    L2 = Len(v) / 5
    Leftover = Len(v) - 5 * L2
    j = 1

    Application.EnableEvents = False
        For i = 1 To L2
            Target.Offset(i - 1, 0).Value = Mid(v, j, 5)
            j = j + 5
        Next i
        If Leftover = 0 Then
        Else
            Target.Offset(L2, 0).Value = Mid(v, j)
            L2 = L2 + 1
        End If
        Target.Offset(L2, 0).Select
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Then click anywhere in column **A** and start typing digits or letters.  When you are done  *(or get tired)* touch the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.
Your data will end up distributed in sets of 5 downwards with the cursor in the first cell below the entered data.

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Comment: Hi Gary, This is such an elegant code. I love it! But still, is it possible to automatically move down the mouse pointer? i tried the below code. but I won't be able to select the cell which already have 5 length digits again.  SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range),  If Len(Target) = 5 Then,  ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

Comment: My interpretation of the question is: when the user inputs 5 digits, excel automatically selects the next cell. I suppose it could be done with a textbox change, but that would be a heck of a lot of textboxes. You have to perform some kind of action in order for the worksheet change event to trigger.

Comment: @Davesexcel Is it possible to do it with simply select and change instead of using textbox?

Comment: @Davesexcel   The real problem is triggering an event while the user is in Edit mode.............might be possible with a UserForm.............

Answer (score 2):

Yep a userform or even an ActiveX textbox could work.

Insert Textbox

[image]

Right click on textbox and select view code.

[image]

use this code there.

[image]

Or copy and paste the code, Make sure textboxes are the same name as in the code

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    If Len(Me.TextBox1) = 5 Then
        Me.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = Me.TextBox1.Value
        Me.TextBox1.Text = ""
    End If
End Sub
```

Start typing in textbox, as soon as you have 5 digits, it will place the text into the 1st empty cell in Column A and clear the textbox.

[image: Enter Text]
[image: Result]

Answer (score 2):

here is an other option that might solve your problem.

1. Open the developer-tool-tab
2. Add a new textbox anywhere on your sheet
3. Add the following code by doubleclicking the textbox.

`Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    If Len(TextBox1.Value) = 5 Then
        ActiveCell.Value = TextBox1.Value
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
        TextBox1.Value = ""
        TextBox1.Activate
    End If
End Sub`

4. Disable the design mode by clicking the triangle with the pen(also in the developer-tool-tab).
5. Make sure you're in the right cell and then start typing in the textbox.

cya 
Amnney